# Changing contact to canonical form (adding + country_code)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, contacts, international-prefix

I am using Samsung Galaxy S2. Is there any automated way or app to change all my contacts with appropriate country code into canonical form.

I just found that lot of my contact are there without the country code. And few apps like whatsapp, viber etc does not recognize the contact unless + is appended with country code.

Is there any better way to do it than editing all my contacts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try syncing your phone contacts with Gmail, preferably into a group.

Then use Gmail's web interface to export that group into a Google CSV format, use a text editor to replace ",00xxx" with ",+xxx" (and do any other editing while you're at it) in the CSV file, and reimport into Gmail.

Comment: +1 for export>edit>import. The 'replace all' function of text editors is about as easy as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to append country code to your contacts or append +91, here is best way to do and be sure of it done:

1. Open the CSV, XLS, or XLSX file as Google spreadsheet
2. Edit > Find and replace
3. Select the option `Search using regular expression`
4. Find ^91 will search all numbers in sheet beginning with 91. In replace, put +91
5. Similarly, do for all contacts of yours with other country codes

Comment: I'm afraid that method doesn't work to add the *appropriate country code*, as the OP needs. Unless the appropriate code is already there, and just the "+" is missing -- the question indicates rather otherwise (country codes completely missing). However, if all contacts are from the same country, and the code is missing everywhere, replacing `^([0-9])` with `+91-\1` (assuming "+91" as the appropriate country code) would do it :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an Android app called [Right Number](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.drzoid.rightnumber) ([source available](http://code.google.com/p/right-number/)) to do exactly what you want. It reformats all the numbers to a canonical form, and then automatically adds the local prefixes whenever you do a call.

Disclaimer: I know personally one of the authors of that app.

Answer (score 0):

How about [Easy Prefix Country Code](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Astalavist4.prependcountrycodefree)?. This adds country code to all contacts selectively.